# Using 'backdrop-filter' and 'padding or border-radius' doesn't work correctly

Tags: css, angular

I'm writing a tooltip, and want a tooltip's blur background. It works incorrectly when I add some 'padding, border-radius' properties.

### Picture 1: Incorrect

[image: Wrong area]

There're the area that is not blur

### Picture 2: Removed the padding, border-radius

[image: img]

### Try without ANGULAR (w3school)

I've already tried without **Angular** It looks wrong too.
**if you see at the top-left corner you will see it is not blur**

[image: img]

[DEMO Link](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G80QORQ78GLD)

c1.component.css

```css
#tooltip {
    /* Add the blur effect */
    backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(8px);

    /* Properties */
    position: absolute;
    left: 467px;
    height: auto;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.788);
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 0.13s;
}
```

I don't know why this code in **Angular** shows some un-blur. There are some ways to deal with the un-blur area.

#### Stackblitz Demo 1: is wrong too

As @Gosha_Fighten provides the stackblitz project the problem still appears as picture below

[image: img]

#### Picture 3: Zoomed

[image]

#### Picture 4: Width is auto

[image]

#### Picture 5: Width is fixed to 150px (OK)

[image]

#### Picture 6: Still not blurred at the top

[image]

Comment: What exact area is not blurred? Does the https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s2wzmr sample reproduce the issue? Would you point me to this area?

Comment: @Gosha_Fighten at the top-left corner you'll see it I have already taken a picture to show you. and W3School Demo is also wrong too if you zoom at the top-left it's too small to see please see at the W3School screenshot too you'll see the shirt texture is so clear at the top of corner

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/c9aNPd1.png for me

What's your browser? Chrome 77.0.3865.90 on my side.

Comment: Do you mean there is no drop shadow at the top left corner?

Comment: @Gosha_Fighten I try the Chrome it looks normal I use the Safari 13.0.1 (15608.2.11.1.1) so the problem belongs to Safari I guess. There's anything I can do now for fixing or avoiding this problem on Safari? by the way, I've just found that when I set the width to an exact number, not to auto It looks fine (as the screenshots)

Comment: @LGSon the top corner is not blurred you will see through it clearly, while below that It's blurred (the image is not clear to see) you can see the w3school picture that I take the screenshot you will find the shirt behind the box is so clear to see the shirt's texture only the top of the box but below of that It cannot see the shirt's texture

Comment: How does this one look for you? https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G8A351NP793Z

Comment: @LGSon As the picture 6 I've just taken the screenshot for you

Comment: @chatdev did you ever determine the underlying cause of this and resolve the issue?

Comment: Apparently this is a webkit bug.